# Using sound_play in ROS custom nodes written in c/c++

Tags: ros, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I successfully managed to get sound_play working on my machine.

I was just wondering if there is a way to use it through c/c++ code within my node.

I found something for python in http://www.pirobot.org/blog/0022/ but not for c/c++.

For the time being I used a system call within the code as follows:
system("rosrun sound_play say.py "Hi There"");

A small barebone example code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41438/using-sound_play-in-ros-custom-nodes-written-in-c/c++/) by [roboviz](https://answers.ros.org/users/685/roboviz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sound_play exposes a C++ API that's documented here: http://docs.ros.org/latest-available/api/sound_play/html/index.html

There's a simple example here: http://docs.ros.org/latest-available/api/sound_play/html/test_8cpp_source.html

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rodrigobdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/27135/rodrigobdz/) on 2016-06-11**:
The links are broken

**Comment by [rodrigobdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/27135/rodrigobdz/) on 2016-06-11**:
The links are now found under the docs directory for each distribution

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-11**:
Fixed the links. Thanks for catching that.